# Problem tidying Jquery in order to debug it

Tags: javascript, debugging, tidy

I'm attempting to debug a block of code and I can't see to get the indentation right. Does anyone have any tools they recommend to auto indent Javascript correctly? I've tried JSTidy and eclipse auto indent.

Comment: If auto indent tools aren't giving you the right indentation, that could be a sign that you have the wrong number of curly brackets in your code.

Comment: @Sam I don't think that's the problem. The code itself works, I just want to change some wording in it.

Comment: I like the IntelliJ family of products - using PyCharm right now and it has a good javascript mode.

Comment: what does [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) say?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbeautifier.org/ is meant to deobfuscate compressed scripts, but it should still do the job.